# Need DOJO calendar that was used in the site Paycheckcity

Tags: dojo, calendar

I would like to develop a dojo calendar as per in the site [PAYCHECKCITY](http://www.paycheckcity.com/calculator/netpay/us/alabama/calculator.html)

I worked out on the text box focus but i would like to have image inside textbox as he had can any one help me out

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5/dojo/dojo.xd.js"
    djConfig="parseOnLoad: true">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        dojo.require("dijit.form.DateTextBox");


    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css"
    />
```

Comment: Can you post the script that you used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the `1.5` with `1.6` you will get automatically.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojo/dojo.xd.js"
    djConfig="parseOnLoad: true">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        dojo.require("dijit.form.DateTextBox");


    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css"
    />
```